Google Sheets - formula for multiple values from different columns are fulfilled
I need to find a formula that can tell me if certain conditions are met in multiple columns.
I have Column A "Day of Week" and Column B "24 Hr Clock"
In column C I would like to show a TRUE value if the conditions met are Monday through Friday between 9 and 19
If the day of the week is Saturday or sunday, or if 24 hr clock is between 19 and 8, column C should show a FALSE Value
I tried this formula and the values I received back were TRUE only for the first condition (eg Monday between 9 and 19)
=AND(A7="Monday", B7>9, B7<19)=OR(A7="Tuesday", B7>9, B7<19)=OR(A7="Wednesay", B7>9, B7<19)=OR(A7="Thursday", B7>9, B7<19)=OR(A7="Friday", B7>9, B7<19)

how are the times in column B formatted? Are they time values? Date & time values? Strings?

Assuming the values in column B are date & time values you can use:
=NOT(OR(LEFT(A2)="S",ISBETWEEN(MOD(B2,1)+(MOD(B2,1)<TIME(8,,)),TIME(19,,),1+TIME(8,,))))

Or by writing times as fractions of days:
=NOT(OR(LEFT(A2)="S",ISBETWEEN(MOD(B2,1)+(MOD(B2,1)<1/3),19/24,4/3)))

If the values in B are just time values you can replace MOD(B2,1) with B2.

Thanks so much.  A colleague just showed me another way that worked too!

=AND(OR(A3="Monday", A3="Tuesday", A3="Wednesday", A3="Thursday", A3="Friday"), B3<19, B3>8)

instead of listing all the days from Monday to Friday you can change that condition to return TRUE if the day is not Saturday or Sunday: =AND(1-REGEXMATCH(A3,"Saturday|Sunday"),B3<19,B3>8). But since Saturday and Sunday are the only days of the week that begin with S you could make this even more concise by just comparing the first letter: =AND(LEFT(A3)<>"S",B3<19,B3>8)

Ah okay, that makes so much sense, thank you!

try:
=INDEX(REGEXMATCH(A3:A, "Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thursday|Friday")*(B3:B<19)*(B3:B>8))

